# R error: filter is longer than time series

Tags: r

I'm trying to reproduce the following code: https://gist.github.com/jdavidson/8591371

I receive the following error:

> Error in filter(geocode_summary, rounds$funded_year == year) : 
>     'filter' is longer than time series

This happens in line 44-48:

```
saveGIF({
for(year in years) {
    print(ggmap(us_map) +
      theme(legend.position=c(.9,.2),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill=alpha("white", .2)),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha("white", .9)),
        axis.line=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
      ggtitle(paste(year)) +
      geom_point(data=filter(geocode_summary, rounds$funded_year == year),
        aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=raised_amount_usd / 1e9), alpha=.6, color="blue") +
      scale_size_area(name="Billions ($)", max_size=20,
        limits=c(1, max(geocode_summary$raised_amount_usd / 1e9))))
}
}, interval=2, movie.name="raised-year.gif", ani.width=640, ani.height=640)
```

Reproducible Example:

This is `rounds`

```
structure(list(company_permalink = c("/organization/1-800-dentist", "/organization/1-800-dentist", "/organization/1000-corks","/organization/1000-markets", "/organization/1000-markets", "/organization/1000-markets", "/organization/1000memories", "/organization/1000memories", "/organization/1000memories", "/organization/1000memories"), company_name = c("1-800-DENTIST", "1-800-DENTIST", "1000 Corks", "1000 Markets", "1000 Markets", "1000 Markets","1000memories", "1000memories", "1000memories", "1000memories"), company_category_list = c("|Health and Wellness|", "|Health and Wellness|", "|Search|", "|Marketplaces|Art|E-Commerce|", "|Marketplaces|Art|E-Commerce|", "|Marketplaces|Art|E-Commerce|", "|Curated Web|", "|Curated Web|", "|Curated Web|", "|Curated Web|"), company_market = c("Health and Wellness", "Health and Wellness", "Search", "Marketplaces", "Marketplaces", "Marketplaces", "Curated Web", "Curated Web", "Curated Web", "Curated Web"), company_country_code = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), company_state_code = c("CA", "CA", "OR", "WA", "WA", "WA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA"), company_region = c("LOS ANGELES", "LOS ANGELES", "PORTLAND, OREGON", "SEATTLE", "SEATTLE", "SEATTLE", "SF BAY AREA", "SF BAY AREA", "SF BAY AREA", "SF BAY AREA"), company_city = c("LOS ANGELES", "LOS ANGELES", "LAKE OSWEGO", "SEATTLE", "SEATTLE", "SEATTLE", "SAN FRANCISCO", "SAN FRANCISCO", "SAN FRANCISCO", "SAN FRANCISCO"), investor_permalink = c("/organization/bain-capital-ventures", "/organization/cue-ball", "/organization/start-up-chile", "/organization/ff-angel-llc", "/organization/true-ventures", "/person/jon-callaghan", "/organization/founder-collective", "/organization/y-combinator", "/organization/felicis-ventures", "/organization/floodgate"), investor_name = c("Bain Capital Ventures", "Cue Ball", "Start-Up Chile", "FF Angel LLC", "True Ventures", "Jon Callaghan", "Founder Collective", "Y Combinator", "Felicis Ventures", "FLOODGATE"), investor_category_list = c("", "|SaaS|Cloud Data Services|Big Data Analytics|Big Data|Information Services|Digital Media|Enterprise Software|", "", "", "|Venture Capital|", "", "|SaaS|Mobile|Quantified Self|E-Commerce|Internet of Things|Software|", "|Startups|Consulting|Venture Capital|Finance|", "|Investment Management|", "|Startups|Venture Capital|Finance|"), investor_market = c("", "Enterprise Software", "", "", "Venture Capital", "", "Software", "Finance", "Investment Management", "Venture Capital"), investor_country_code = c("USA", "USA", "CHL", "USA", "USA", "", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), 
investor_state_code = c("MA", "MA", "", "CA", "CA", "", "MA", 
"CA", "CA", "CA"), investor_region = c("Boston", "Boston", 
"Santiago", "SF Bay Area", "SF Bay Area", "", "Boston", "SF Bay Area", 
"SF Bay Area", "SF Bay Area"), investor_city = c("Boston", 
"Boston", "Santiago", "San Francisco", "Palo Alto", "", "Cambridge", 
"Mountain View", "Palo Alto", "Palo Alto"), funding_round_permalink = c("/funding-round/5274aacc211163fc7c86539ce94bbacc", 
"/funding-round/5274aacc211163fc7c86539ce94bbacc", "/funding-round/8f4fa70e24269ddd8bdf6658906b356b", 
"/funding-round/ce6749b6441f52ccaf38b6d5578779fd", "/funding-round/ce6749b6441f52ccaf38b6d5578779fd", 
"/funding-round/ce6749b6441f52ccaf38b6d5578779fd", "/funding-round/f5fb428ed1e63321f88b3e646ba85f00", 
"/funding-round/f5fb428ed1e63321f88b3e646ba85f00", "/funding-round/502bd0e50c27616995e4bdad24605ef8", 
"/funding-round/502bd0e50c27616995e4bdad24605ef8"), funding_round_type = c("undisclosed", 
"undisclosed", "seed", "seed", "seed", "seed", "seed", "seed", 
"venture", "venture"), funding_round_code = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "A", "A"), funded_at = structure(c(14822, 
14822, 15187, 14365, 14365, 14365, 14610, 14610, 15006, 15006
), class = "Date"), funded_month = c("2010-08", "2010-08", 
"2011-08", "2009-05", "2009-05", "2009-05", "2010-01", "2010-01", 
"2011-02", "2011-02"), funded_quarter = c("2010-Q3", "2010-Q3", 
"2011-Q3", "2009-Q2", "2009-Q2", "2009-Q2", "2010-Q1", "2010-Q1", 
"2011-Q1", "2011-Q1"), funded_year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L), raised_amount_usd = c(NA, 
NA, 40000, 5e+05, 5e+05, 5e+05, 15000, 15000, 2520000, 2520000
), geocode = c("LOS ANGELES CA USA", "LOS ANGELES CA USA", 
"PORTLAND, OREGON OR USA", "SEATTLE WA USA", "SEATTLE WA USA", 
"SEATTLE WA USA", "SF BAY AREA CA USA", "SF BAY AREA CA USA", 
"SF BAY AREA CA USA", "SF BAY AREA CA USA")), .Names = c("company_permalink", "company_name", "company_category_list", "company_market", "company_country_code", "company_state_code", "company_region", "company_city", "investor_permalink", "investor_name", "investor_category_list", "investor_market", "investor_country_code", "investor_state_code", "investor_region", "investor_city", "funding_round_permalink", "funding_round_type", "funding_round_code", "funded_at", "funded_month", "funded_quarter", "funded_year", "raised_amount_usd", "geocode"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

This is `geocode_summary`

```
structure(list(geocode = c("LOS ANGELES CA USA", "PORTLAND, OREGON OR USA", 
"SEATTLE WA USA", "SF BAY AREA CA USA", "SF BAY AREA CA USA", 
"SEATTLE WA USA", "NEW YORK CITY NY USA", "HUNTSVILLE AL USA", 
"PROVIDENCE RI USA", "LOS ANGELES CA USA"), funded_year = c(2010L, 
2011L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L
), rounds = c(302L, 107L, 180L, 2829L, 3903L, 265L, 841L, 1L, 
27L, 287L), raised_amount_usd = c(2699217887, 807773000, 15172711760, 
29348141361, 51835224232, 1428015838, 4839925602, 1800000, 104189000, 
3206791194), X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L), lon = c(-118.2436849, 
-122.6764816, -122.3320708, -122.2913078, -122.2913078, -122.3320708, 
-74.0059413, -86.5861037, -71.4128343, -118.2436849), lat = c(34.0522342, 
45.5230622, 47.6062095, 37.8271784, 37.8271784, 47.6062095, 40.7127837, 
34.7303688, 41.8239891, 34.0522342)), .Names = c("geocode", "funded_year", 
"rounds", "raised_amount_usd", "X", "lon", "lat"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Which data did you provide here, `geocode_summary` or `rounds`? Where is the other one?

Comment: I edited my question, know I provide rounds and geocode_summary

Comment: Next time, please manually remove the `.internal.selfref` from your data. The data will not load if that is still in the text to be copied. (This is an easy/common oversight.)